# Bell number as summation of Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

> A different summation formula represents each Bell number as a sum of
>   Stirling numbers of the second kind
>
> $ B_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \left\{{n\atop k}\right\} $
>
> The Stirling number $\left\{{n\atop k}\right\} $ is the number of ways
>   to partition a set of cardinality n into exactly k nonempty subsets.
>   Thus, in the equation relating the Bell numbers to the Stirling
>   numbers, each partition counted on the left hand side of the equation
>   is counted in exactly one of the terms of the sum on the right hand
>   side, the one for which k is the number of sets in the partition.

I was reading wiki and found the summation starts from $0$ instead of $1$. Is not that logically incorrect? Set partition never allowed to be empty. Can anybody clarify?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Stirling number $n\brace k$ is actually defined for all pairs of non-negative integers. Of course ${n\brace k}=0$ when $k>n$. Since a non-empty set cannot have a partition into $0$ parts, it’s also clear that we want ${n\brace 0}=0$ for $n>0$. It turns out, however, to be convenient to set ${0\brace 0}=1$, as it makes recurrence

$${{n+1}\brace k}=k{n\brace k}+{n\brace{k-1}}$$

behave nicely.

Comment: @ViX28: You’re welcome.